# Android - Share Remote Image without Downloading

Tags: android, picasso, shareactionprovider

Is it possible to share a remote image with a ShareActionProvider without downloading the image?

I'm currently downloading the remote url image first and then sharing that via the explanation found here: http://guides.thecodepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

However I've noticed when testing with Facebook, that after you share an image on Facebook there is no downloaded image stored on your phone. I'm assuming FB loads their images remotely but I could be wrong in that regard I guess.

My only other thought would be that they delete the downloaded image after it is successfully shared.

So my question being, is it possible to:

a) Share a remote image without downloading it?

or

b) Delete the shared image after it being sent, with some sort of callback and delete function?

Thanks

**Edit**:
Mentioned slightly here as well [Get image uri from picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693665/get-image-uri-from-picasso?rq=1)

**Edit**: Facebook, and Google+ don't download the image being shared from what I can tell, Instagram and Pinterest both bypass this issue by only sharing the images url, not the actual image. (Any other apps I'm not sure of)

Answer (score 0):

If Facebook can access the image's URL (it isn't on some secure domain), you can just send them the URL without downloading / uploading it to the client

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to do something like this then?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300959/android-share-image-from-url