# Picasso Image downloaded again for an ImageView with different dimensions?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm using Picasso in my application for loading image efficiently and is doing his job at the best.The issue is that, currently if i call  `Picasso.with()` multiple times with same url, however each time with an image view having different dimensions, the image gets downloaded again.In `Glide` we have the methods  `.diskCacheStrategy()` with `DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE` for resolving the problem.is there any alternative way in Picasso ?

In [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/238) query we will get the solution for Glid but not for Picasso.how can i reuse the image without redownloading for different dimensions ImageView.

This is the code I'm using

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(URI)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_profile_thumb)
                .resize(180, 180).centerInside()
                .into(viewHolder.imgThumbnail);
```

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28964219/1384010 .Hope this will help you !!

Comment: Could you paste your code related to Picasso? Are you using the resize option?

Comment: @Scotti plz check my code.I'm using resize op.

Comment: @Stella: Did you check the HTTP headers of the image file in question? If they don't allow caching then OkHttp or Volley will probably just download it again - as they should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Picasso does not cache the image to disk, Picasso only has a memory cache. the Disk cache is done by the networking library(OKhttp). so the image written to the disk cache is never re-sized.

if the same url image is downloaded multiple time you might have to check your networking library.

If your project is using the okhttp library then picasso will automatically use it as the default downloader. If you are are using any other network library then you will have to write your own downloader and set it using

```
Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(customDownloader)
```

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280242/using-picasso-with-custom-disk-cache) might make things clear

Comment: Can u please interpret your answer with actual code for this worry ? I'm using volley as my n/w library.

Comment: - Picasso offers automatic memory and disk cache out of the box. Check out my answer above.
- AFAIK the image in the disk cache is resized if you use the resize() method.

Comment: @Sotti Picasso doesn't have a disk cache. check the answer by jake here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280242/using-picasso-with-custom-disk-cache

Comment: @billgates: Well, I don't know what has happened since that threat 2 years ago. Something more recent is this one (https://goo.gl/1V4Vps) or the Picasso webpage (http://square.github.io/picasso/) where they say Picasso offers "Automatic memory and disk caching.". I'm not saying the Http client is not involved, but whatever the client is been used (OkHttp, HttpUrlConnection...) looks like the disk is somehow involved and Picasso is making use of it with its Network.Policy attributes. Not completely clear to me tho at this point.

Comment: @Sotti: The first link you provided (the Github issue) actually confirms that Picasso still relies on OkHttp to do any disk caching. As Jake confirms, the correct/only way to increase the size of the disc cache is by *increasing the cache size of the OkHttpDowloader*, which in turn sets the cache size of Picasso's OkHttpClient.

Answer (score 5):

Picasso by default doesn't resize images. If you do a simple call like the next one...

```
Picasso.with(context).load("https://goo.gl/v9EkbF").into(imageView);
```

...Picasso is caching the full-size image. From that moment, every time you call the same URL, Picasso will reuse that full-size image and let the GPU do the resizing into the view.

Use the resize() method you are only caching the resized image, and Picasso will need to download the image again if you use a different size.

Don't use the resize() option and you'll get better bandwidth usage, but be careful with memory usage.

**The defaults in Picasso**

Picasso *does have* automatic memory and *disk* caching. Any image that was requested recently will be in memory cache. If it isn't there Picasso will check the disk cache. If it's not available on disk, only then Picasso will start the network request.

**All requested images are stored in both caches** until they have to be deleted in order to free space.

The default's in 2.5.2 are:

- LRU memory cache of 15% the available application RAM
- Disk cache of 2% storage space up to 50MB but no less than 5MB.
- Picasso will use OkHttp as the Http client if it's included as a Gradle dependency. Otherwise Picasso will fall back to HttpUrlConnection.

You can increase the disk cache like this (example for 100MB):

```
    Picasso picasso =  new Picasso
        .Builder(this)
        .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(getCacheDir(), 100000000))
        .build();

    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
```

Changing the disc cache size *does not* change the cache policy.

**Memory Policies**

- MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE: The image won't be served from memory. This one doesn't avoid to serve images from disk. To avoid disk look down on *Network Policies*.
- MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE: The image won't be stored in memory. Use this for images that will be loaded only once.

Example

```
Picasso
        .with(context)
        .load(https://goo.gl/v9EkbF)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .into(imageView);
```

**Network Policies**

- NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE: The image won't be served from disk cache.
- NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE: The image will (if possible) be served just from cache (memory or disk) but  never from network.

Example:

```
Picasso
        .with(context)
        .load(https://goo.gl/v9EkbF)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
        .into(imageView);
```

**Memory and caching considerations**

- Glide uses by default RGB565 and cache a image resized into the
  memory.
- Picasso uses by default RGB888 and cache the full size image into the
  memory and let GPU does the real-time resizing when drawn.

RGB565 is half the size of RGB888. The result of using RGB565 and smaller images is that Picasso memory footprint is higher (might be 3x/4x) than Glide's.

Those are just the defaults. Glide can be configured to use RGB888 and Picasso to use RGB565. Picasso can be configured to throw into memory just the resized images like Glide.

Under the same setups, the memory footprint is almost the same.

**Bandwidth considerations**

- Glide caches separate file for each size. If you load another size of
  the same image, it will be downloaded again before, resized and then
  cached.
- Picasso takes always the full-size image from cache and then let the GPU make the resizing into the view.

You can ask Glide to cache everything, full-size image and resized images but by default Glide's bandwidth consumption is higher.

**Note**

[Picasso 2.6](https://goo.gl/xa9NtO) is coming and I have no idea about what's different/new.

**Sources**

- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
- [Introduction to Glide, Image Loader Library for Android, recommended
  by Google](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)
- [What is default cache policy?](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1154)
- [Picasso — Influencing Image Caching](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-influencing-image-caching)

Comment: Any references about this?: `Picasso has "Automatic memory and disk caching` i couldn't find that in: https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Good point, it was under the all items, i didn't see it :) +1 and thank you for mentioning about it, i just updated the answer.

Comment: 1) picasso does not have a disk cache it is delegated to the network layer
2) Even if resize() is called the image in the Disk cache (network layer) is not resized.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OkHttp` from the same vendor "SquareUp".
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686992/244702) show you how to do it with details.

Comment: So, if i use cached image when the URL remains same but the image upating means what i should do to overcome that.I mean in `glide` we got `signature()` method any alternative in picasso ?

Comment: Either you use OkHttp (that Picasso will use under the hood if it's included in the project) or you use HttpUrlConnection (that Picasso will use as a fallback in case OkHttp is not included and no other is defined) the cache policy has to be defined and can be defined via Picasso without going much deeper. The main question/problem scope is not very clear tho to me, could be something as simple as not using the resize() method.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** The links were old, by the way, Here are the changes in the newest versions:

https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

And as @Sotti said, `Picasso` has **`Automatic memory and disk caching`** which they mentioned about that in the Introduction section:(the last part)**

http://square.github.io/picasso/#introduction

---

> In this query we will get the solution for Glid but not for
>   Picasso.how can i reuse the image **without redownloading for different
>   dimensions `ImageView`**.

Actually, `Picasso` only has a **memory cache**, But you may want to use `OkHttp` for that.

Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18552559/4409113 Which says:

> If you are referring about the disk cache, *then no Picasso does not
>   support that at the moment*. This is by design because the disk layer
>   cache is done by the `HTTP layer` and makes no distinction about it.

Check this out too: https://corner.squareup.com/2013/05/picasso-one-dot-oh.html

> Picasso automatically utilizes **a memory and disk cache** (**provided by
>   the `HTTP client`**) to speed up bitmap loading. For development you can
>   enable the display of a colored marker which indicates the image
>   source.

And also, check this question: [How to implement my own disk cache with picasso library - Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944773/how-to-implement-my-own-disk-cache-with-picasso-library-android)

To save the files in *custom cache directory* using `OkHttp`:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
File customCacheDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/MyCache");
okHttpClient.setCache(new Cache(customCacheDirectory, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
OkHttpDownloader okHttpDownloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(mainActivity).downloader(okHttpDownloader).build();
picasso.load(imageURL).into(viewHolder.image);
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33276054/4409113

As you can see, uses [`setCache`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#setCache-com.squareup.okhttp.Cache-).

---

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out, that OkHttp will still only cache the images *if the HTTP headers allow caching* - I once had a client complain that images weren't reloaded every day and then the image file had a header like `Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2017 00:00:00 GMT`.

Comment: @david.mihola - Hmm, thanks for sharing the experiences btw.

Comment: Your link to the Square blog is 3 years old and for the version 1.0. Today the version 2.5.2 has been out for a while and the version 2.6 is near. You can read in their webpage that Picasso has "Automatic memory and disk caching." (http://goo.gl/tpTc1)